# How long express-session stays stored?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, express-session

I have a project based on nodes as follows:

```
"express": "~4.13.1",
"express-sequelize-session": "^0.4.0",
"express-session": "^1.12.1"
```

As I have strict limitations of db rows amount, may major concern is: how long the session is stored in db, is there any way to modify these limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `express-sequelize-session` listed in supported stores in  [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

You can use [connect-session-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-session-sequelize) and specify the expiration.

Copy paste from the readme

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  store: new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize,
    checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, // The interval at which to cleanup expired sessions in milliseconds.
    expiration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000  // The maximum age (in milliseconds) of a valid session.
  })
}))
```